# INFINITE LOOPING AFTER FAILED TO DELETE THE OS

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop

A few months ago I tried to delete my OS because of virus. But when I try to delete it, I didn't realize that my laptop's battery has already run out of power. So it's just shutdown.

After that I tried to activate my laptop again but it's just stuck in infinite loop. I've tried to get into windows boot manager (so I can just install a new OS), but when I do that it's just shutdown and do the infinite loop again.
The loop happen after the lenovo logo appear.

Please tell me how to fix that.

Comment: Windows Boot Manager won't let you install a new OS, it's not one of its features. And you don't need it, Windows installation media will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using windows. Assuming Windows 10, get an installation disk, plug it in, and reinstall windows using the Custom option. In more detail:

1. Get an EMPTY 8GB usb drive. It WILL be erased.
2. Get another windows computer, open a web browser, and go [to this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO), select your settings, then download the 32-bit ISO if the computer you broke was 32 bit, or the 64-bit ISO if it was 64-bit.
3. Plug the usb drive into the other computer. [Download Rufus here](https://rufus.ie/), (make sure you choose the portable version), open it by double clicking.
4. If it asks you about updates, select no. From the Device drop-down, select your empty USB drive.
5. From the Boot selection drop down, make sure Disk or ISO image is selected.
6. Click select and locate the ISO image you downloaded. Click open and Rufus will inspect the ISO.
7. If under the Image Option area you see **Standard Windows installation** *select that.* Leave everything as it is and hit start.
8. Address any dialogs you get, and let Rufus download any additional files it needs.
9. Once the status says READY (this could take upwards of 20 minutes), remove the USB drive and plug it into your nonfunctional computer.
10. Turn on your computer and immediately start pressing F12 over and over again as fast as you can. Continue doing this until you see a list of boot options. Select the USB drive and press enter on your keyboard.
11. Proceed with the windows installation as normal. Have your computer plugged in during this process. If you choose the Custom option as recommended, all data will be deleted. When you get to the product key section, select I don’t have a product key and depending on how badly you destroyed Windows it should figure out what it is for you.

Comment: In addition to what @TCoder said, you can install your new copy of Windows on a newly created partition (the installer will allow you to do that, either when you get to choose on which existing partition you want to install, or via Repair this computer / Advanced / Command line with "diskpart", instead of Install, in the first menu), so that you can salvage some of the data that might still be on your hard drive. You may have "deleted" Windows, but there's a good chance most of your data hasn't been overwritten yet, so you can probably save most of it, provided you install on a new partition.

Comment: Correct. Windows probably wasn’t “deleted”, you probably just destroyed your MBR or EFI partition which will destroy the operating system but not your data. Good luck!

Comment: @E Sa: one thing you can try once you've booted from the Windows install USB stick or DVD is to choose Repair / Advanced / Command Line, and at the prompt, type "bootsect /nt60 all /force" (without quotes), and press Enter. You should get a "Successfully updated NTFS filesystem bootcode.
Bootcode was successfully updated on all targeted volumes." return, at which point you can try and restart Windows normally. If you still can't, then you'll have to reinstall as TCorder suggested.

Comment: Yep, attempting to rebuild the boot data is a good idea. Try this first.

Comment: Thankyou guys. My laptop's fixed now because of you. :)

Comment: Always good to help someone!